# Why vcpkg can't install packages?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

When I try to install **matplotlib-cpp** using **vcpkg**, the console always returns `Computing installation plan...`, then nothing happens. After that, I checked the installation package with `.\vcpkg list`. It seems that this package has not been installed.
I also tried to install other packages and encountered the same situation.

**Environment**:

1. Windows 10, 64 bit build 19042
2. Visual Studio 2019
3. cmake 3.21.0-rc2
4. Git

[The scene where the problem occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXpsO.png)

Comment: Oh, I reinstalled cmake 3.20.5, and then vcpkg worked.

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into this. Extremely painful to find as CMake seems to work otherwise. If you use vcpkg at all I would advise not trying CMake 3.21.0 until this is fixed.